# How to update existing custom options for product?

Tags: magento2, custom-options

I have created custom options programatically with reference of below url :
https://webkul.com/blog/create-custom-option-programmatically-in-magento2/
How to update any option value or option details programatically for options which are already added in product.

Answer (score 0):

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$productId = 1;
$_product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface')->getById($productId, true);
$newValues = array();
foreach ($_product->getOptions() as $option) {
           $optionValues = $option->getValues();
        }
    }
  foreach($optionValues as $value)
        {
            $newValues[$value->getId()]['option_type_id']= $value->getId();
                $newValues[$value->getId()]['title']= 'Custom Title';
                $newValues[$value->getId()]['price']= 100;
                $newValues[$value->getId()]['price_type']= 'fixed';

          }
        $value->setValues($newValues);
        $value->saveValues();
$_product->save();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
$product->setData('your_option_name', $yourOptionValue);

$product->save();
```